Post files using Swagger open api 2.0 - custom connector in power automate
I have used this below swagger open api definition to create custom connector with on-premise gateway.
I used this custom connector in Power automate.
the file content field appears as [body] instead of [file]. I cannot post this because the api this connector is calling expects a file parameter
see image below.
Can someone please help me as how I can modify the swagger so that this [body] field to appear as [file] in power automate
I spent lot of days trying to fix this.
swagger definition 2.0
"post": {
                "responses": {
                    "default": {
                        "description": "default",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/RecordsResponse"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "summary": "Create or Update Record",
                "consumes": ["multipart/form-data"],
                "description": "Create or update a Record",
                "operationId": "CreateUpdateRecord",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "properties",
                        "in": "formData",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "RecordTitle,RecordNumber",
                        "x-ms-visibility": "internal"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "RecordContainer",
                        "in": "formData",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "RecordRecordType",
                        "in": "formData",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    { "name": "RecordTitle", "in": "formData", "type": "string" },
                                        { "name": "Fields", "in": "formData", "type": "string"},    
                    { "name": "file","in": "formData", "type": "file" }
                ]
            }



